# 1 button 3 functions Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, button

Image :

[image]

Hi everyone. i would like some help about my code. What am i doing is a button for 1, A & B like a keypad phone but i dont get it.If I click the button then choose A the button click must be stop then the next character would be B it erases the first input .Is there something im missing

```
Dim Button1_Stage As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

 Select Case Button1_Stage
        Case 0
            Textbox11.text = "1"
            Button1_Stage += 1
        Case 1
            Textbox.text = "A"
            Button1_Stage += 1
        Case 2
            Textbox1.tecxt = "B"
            Button1_Stage += 1
        Case 3
            Button1_Stage = 0
    End Select
End Sub
```

Thanks for anyone who will help

Comment: guys any help anyone?

Comment: Some advice: Tag your post with the programming language instead of putting it in the title - this will make sure the right people get to see your post because they're not searching titles but subscribe to language tags. Nobody is looking at generic tags like *"button"* or *"project"*.

Comment: I cant it requires at least 1500 reputation :(

Comment: looks like a smartphone. Meaning that you don't _click_, but _touch_, and that is a different behavior and different events raised. Explain this first

Comment: You don't need the 1.500 rep to create a new tag - you can simply use the existing vb.net tag just the same as you did use *"button"*.

Comment: @Thomas G any help? Someone told me a timeout but I can't do it since I'm new to VB